# I don't understand how INSTANCE.let block work in this code

Tags: kotlin, android-room

now i am learning Room in https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view-kotlin/#11

and i can not understand the code

```
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
                }
            }
```

why does INSTANCE.let block exist 
what is different that

```
        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            scope.launch {
                populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
            }
        }
```

this is full code

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Word::class), version = 1, exportSchema = false)
abstract class WordRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun wordDao(): WordDao

    private class WordDatabaseCallback(
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : RoomDatabase.Callback() {

        override fun onOpen(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onOpen(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
                }
            }
        }

        suspend fun populateDatabase(wordDao: WordDao) {
            wordDao.deleteAll()

            wordDao.insert(Word("Hello"))
            wordDao.insert(Word("World!"))
        }
    }

    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: WordRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ): WordRoomDatabase {
            val tempInstance = INSTANCE
            if (tempInstance != null) {
                return tempInstance
            }
            synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    WordRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "word_database"
                ).addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it says if the INSTANCE is not null then run the following block of code (lambda) and returns the result of the lambda. IMHO there should be `also{}` used instead of the let since you don't use the result anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.let { }` is a scoping function. Scoping functions allow us to write concise code. Let examine this little code:

`INSTANCE`: represents the instance of your Room database.

`?` : says, "if the value is **not null**"

`scope` represents a scope on which a Coroutine runs.

`INSTANCE?.let { it -> }`: says that (look at the question mark above), if `INSTANCE` is **not null**, create a scope which exposes a copy of the  **non-null** `INSTANCE`. `it`is just a default name, you can name it to anything just like a variable.

So:

```
   INSTANCE?.let { database ->  //database (or 'it') is not null
            scope.launch { 
                populateDatabase(database.wordDao()) //Now pre-populate the database.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, this code

```
 INSTANCE?.let { database ->
            scope.launch {
                populateDatabase(database.wordDao())
            }
 }
```

is just a more elegant way to write this:

```
if (INSTANCE != nil) {
     scope.launch {
        populateDatabase(INSTANCE!!.wordDao())
     }
}
```